# ARCore – Cloud Anchors for more than 24 hours or Feature Points for more than 7 days

Tags: android, augmented-reality, arcore

Is it possible to have `Cloud Anchors` be accessed after 24 hours and/or the feature points re-activated?

Answer (score 1):

According to Google [documentation](https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/cloud-anchors/overview-android):

> In ARCore 1.20 and later, Cloud Anchors can be resolved for **365 days** after they are hosted. In versions of ARCore earlier than 1.20, Cloud Anchors could be resolved only for 24 hours after they were hosted.

If you're using ARCore 1.12 ... ARCore 1.19 – it's still impossible to access Cloud Anchors after 24 hours. Also Point Cloud is discarded after 7 days. It's potentially possible to use your own hosting service for Cloud Anchors, but in that case you'll be unable to use an ARCore Cloud Anchor API.

> Once an Anchor is hosted successfully, the anchor becomes a Cloud Anchor and is assigned a unique Cloud Anchor ID. After this it lives twenty-four hours. Anchor IDs are exchanged using Firebase Realtime Database.

Anchors are resolved on the server side against the stored sparse point map.

Comment: so is there a way to host cloud anchors on my private server?

Comment: @GokulDAS027, potentially you can, but it has no sense because you can't use Cloud Anchor API.

Comment: Ooh, we will have to do it all on ourselves right? like Azure api streaming frames to cloud..